# SSRS multi-select parameter can't capture values with comma

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a multi-select parameter that has comma on it's list and my dataset is using a function split for my parameter since it's in a SP so my where clause looks like this:

```
WHERE [CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME] IN (SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.FnSplit(@ProductDivision,','))
```

and for example, "SMART-UPS 1,5KVA" and "BACK-UPS" were ticked in the multi-select parameter, the multi-select will treat the first value as two different values which are "SMART-UPS 1" and 5KVA". So in my Split function it will show this result:

```
  Row Value
   1  SMART-UPS 1
   2  5KVA
   3  BACK-UPS
```

And since "SMART-UPS 1" and "5KVA" were not a valid value, I will not get the records under "SMART-UPS 1,5KVA".

Can someone give ideas on how to solve this problem? Any response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: might be a good reason to store the values in a separate table with ID's and pass the ID's in to your stored proc instead of the Text values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this one can be quite simple: Just use a different seperator!
(In this case i use ";" but you could use almost any symbol, which does not appear in your LOV.

When passing the Parameters, set the Paramter Value in the Dataset Properties to

```
=Join(Parameters!ProductDivision.Value, ";")
```

In your SQL-Code then adjust the where clause to

```
WHERE [CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME] IN (SELECT VALUE FROM DBO.FnSplit(@ProductDivision,';'))
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Wow this works like a charm! Thank you so much Mossi!

Comment: No problem, i use this method every other day

Answer (score 1):

**You should store the values in a separate table.  Show the description and make the value of the list-items their respective IDs.  Then, you'll never have a comma in your string parameter.**

If that's not an option:

Before building your string (within your application), replace all comma values with something that you know won't appear naturally.

For example, if you've selected the following values:

```
 1. SPK,5
 2. Joe
 3. Dave,Smith
```

You can iterate through those items and replace the commas with something like ten asterisks: "**********"

So your final string would be "SPK**********5,Joe,Dave**********Smith".  You would also want to pass the replacement string as a second parameter (so you can change your app without having to modify your SP).

Then, you can use the following logic:

```
WHERE [CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME] IN (SELECT REPLACE(VALUE, @SecondParameter, ',') FROM DBO.FnSplit(@ProductDivision,','))
```

This way, everything will be split correctly, since you've removed the commas.  Then, when you select from that list, you just replace the funny character string (in this example, ten asterisks) with the original comma.

For the record, you should 100% do what I initially suggested.  This is a terrible approach, but it will get you out of a jam.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to response with my question. I appreciate it. Though, I found a much easier solution. It was from Mossi's response.

Comment: @Aldrin No problem, although his answer is the same as mine, only has more potential for error.  From my answer "replace all comma values with something that you know won't appear naturally".  The ten asterisks was an example.  If a semicolon won't appear naturally, it's the same thing.  However, you're better passing it as a parameter because if ever an option is included in your list that has a semicolon (if that's your chosen delimiter), then you would have to modify both the app and the SP, instead of just one.  Best of luck to you, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass parameters as table parameter:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #t(CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME)
VALUES ('SMART-UPS 1,5KVA'), ('BACK-UPS');


DECLARE @t TABLE (val VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t(val) VALUES ('SMART-UPS 1,5KVA'),('BACK-UPS');

SELECT *
FROM #t
WHERE CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME IN (SELECT val FROM @t);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483215)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ CURRENTPRODATT_DIV_NAME ║
╠════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ SMART-UPS 1,5KVA        ║
║  2 ║ BACK-UPS                ║
╚════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my example to be more clear with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So my guess that the string you pass is a string like param,value,param,value and you want only the values from the string.

If you know that values can't be 'PARAMETER'. You could do like this

```
declare @params varchar(max) = 'PARAMETER1,AAA,PARAMETER2,BBB'

SELECT VALUE  FROM dbo.FnSplit(@params,',')
WHERE VALUE  NOT LIKE 'PARAMETER%'
```

The output of this query is

```
----------
AAA
BBB
```

Edit:

In case you have parameter as a value and you know that there always will be param,value,param,value string. You could use a CTE

```
declare @params varchar(max) = 'PARAMETER1,AAA,PARAMETER2,BBB'; 
WITH VALUE AS
(
    SELECT VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as RN 
    FROM dbo.FnSplit(@params,',')
)

SELECT * FROM VALUE
WHERE RN % 2 = 0
```

So what you do here, you split the string and save the rownumber and you also know that values will always have an even Rownumber.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry if my post is confusing. The value I want to get is the "PARAMETER1,AAA" in just 1 string not spliting them into 2. I'll edit my post and give other example.

Comment: @Aldreenzy and how SQL know which ',' is good for splitting and which is not. From what I understood your values can contain commas, but there is no way the SQL could know what ',' is a spliter and which is not. You either use a diferent spliter or comeup with an algorith that could tell you that one comma is or not a spliter.

Comment: Yeah, correct. So I will really have to tweak my split function. Thanks for the advice.